# dojo.query "," (or) for combining multiple selections does not work on IE 7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, dojo, css-selectors

I am using

```
dojo.query('input,select',myDiv)[0].focus();
```

to focus the first input element found in a div container.

This will work in Firefox, but not in IE 7.

IE 7 only takes the first query into consideration:

```
dojo.query('input,select')[0] will select the first input element, 
  even if a select element is first.

dojo.query('select,input')[0] will select the first select element, 
  even if an input element is first.
```

Does anybody know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, `dojo.query` does not necessarily guarantee "chronological" order within the NodeList it returns, especially for complex queries.  This is generally due to the fact that for some browsers / in some scenarios, it does have to cobble multiple disparate result sets together, and trying to reorder this based on where each element is in the document would probably be far more of a performance hit than it's worth.

That said, off the cuff I'm not sure what to suggest as an alternative.  It'd be easy enough to find the first of one OR the other separately, just not while looking for both within the same query.

If your form has some kind of consistent markup around your inputs (e.g. each field is inside let's say, a div with `class="field"`), I suppose you could do something like this:

```
dojo.query('.field:first-child select, .field:first-child input')
```

Comment: Thanks, I went around the problem by classing all elements as field and using the :first-child approach with just one alternative.